# Repeat column only ones for a id in MySQL result

Tags: mysql, sql, database, join

I am stuck with a problem while writing a MySQL query. There are two tables :

Orders:

```
| id   | item_id | delivery_charges |
|------|---------|------------------|
| 1000 | 11      | 17.7             |
| 2000 | 22      | 17.7             |
```

Order_items

```
| id  | order_id |
|-----|----------|
| 111 | 1000     |  
| 112 | 1000     |
| 113 | 2000     |
| 114 | 2000     |
| 115 | 2000     |
```

result

```
| id   | order_id | delivery_charges |
|------|----------|------------------|
| 111  | 1000     | 17.7             |
| 112  | 1000     | 17.7             |
| 113  | 2000     | 17.7             |
| 114  | 2000     | 17.7             |
| 115  | 2000     | 17.7             |
```

Desired result

```
| id  | order_id | delivery_charges |
|-----|----------|------------------|
| 111 | 1000     | 17.7             |
| 112 | 1000     |                  |
| 113 | 2000     | 17.7             |
| 114 | 2000     |                  |
| 115 | 2000     |                  |
```

I have performed an inner join on both the tables joining id from Orders table with order_id of the order_items table.

As you can see in the result table.

But what I want is that result should not contain repeated delivery charge.

It should only contain single delivery charge value for each id in an order_items table or we can say that there should be only one delivery_charge value for same order_ids in the result.

Please help me with this.

Comment: my sql version name please?

Comment: I am using version 5.6.

Comment: Where do ids 114 and 115 come from?  They are not in the sample data.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I have updated the sample data, forgot to add these ids in Order_items.

Answer (score 1):

you need row_number() function to do your result but mysql 5.6 does not row_number function so tried it manually

```
     select t1.id,t1.order_id ,case when rank=1 then 
  delivery_charges else null end as  delivery_charges  from
        (
         select  t.*, 
               @rownum := @rownum + 1 AS rank from 
        (
        select ot.*,o.delivery_charges
         Orders o inner join
         Order_items ot on o.id =ot.order_id 
        )  as t , (SELECT @rownum := 0) r   
        )    as t1
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming I understand the question, you can do this without window functions or variables:

```
select oi.*,
       (case when oi.id = oim.first_id then o.delivery_charge end) as delivery_charge
from orders o join
     order_items oi
     on o.id = oi.order_id join
     (select oi2.order_id, min(oi2.id) as first_id
      from order_items oi2
      group by oi2.order_id
     ) oim
     on oim.order_id = oi.order_id;
```

This can also be phrased as:

```
select oi.*, oim.delivery_charge
from order_items oi join
     (select o.id, min(oi2.id) as first_id,
             min(o.delivery_charge) as delivery_charge
      from order_items oi2 join
           orders o
            on oi2.order_id = o.id
      group by o.id
     ) oim
     on oim.order_id = oi.order_id;
```

Comment: Thank you very much @Gordon your 1st solution worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm wrong, but it could be related with a Cartesian Products in SQL
I have not the exact answer but it could help
[image]

Apply logic according with the JOIN clause and try!